# Why same code works and does not work in another form

Tags: javascript

I have two javascript codes . 
Two codes working for the same work , but there is one code work and the other code does not work .

**Work**

```
var i = 0;
function slideShow(){
    i++;
    document.getElementsByName('SearchBox')[0].value = i
    setTimeout(slideShow, 1000);
}
```

**Not work**

```
var i = 0;
function slideShow(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        i++;
        document.getElementsByName('SearchBox')[0].value = i
    }, 1000);
}
```

Why one works and the other does not work

Comment: because they are not the same.  if(old == new) { same; }

Comment: Does "does not work" result in any error message?

Comment: @Uwe Keim: no any error message

Comment: Please explain _how_ it doesn't work.

Comment: Steady on; It may not be a well written question, but it _is_ fairly clear what the problem is. If you want to turn the question into something useful, provide a useful answer, not just a useless comment

Comment: @Flimzy: I do not know why it does not work , If i know why I does not work I did not add a question

Comment: I'm not asking _why_ it doesn't work, I'm asking _how_ it doesn't work. What are the symptoms of it not working?

Comment: @Flimzy: Unfortunately, there are not any error messages appear

Comment: Indeed, "not working" is quite subjective. The code does *something* without error, how's that "not working"? We can all infer what you mean in this case, but please, **provide a description of the actual problem** when asking a question. I think you'd have seen the solution yourself trying to put the problem into words. :)

Comment: Error messages are not the only possible symptoms of something not working. I'm glad that others were able to see the failure despite the lack of description.

Comment: The purpose of the code is to increase i variable at a time with the show the value of the variable in the text box , in the first example works well and shows the variable value to increase , But in the second example does not work and remains the value of the variable is one and does not increase

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first version, when called, does something, then sets a timeout to call itself again.

The second version, when called, sets a timeout to execute some code. It does **not call itself again**.

Answer (score 1):

In the first example, `slideShow` passes itself to `setTimeout`, so every time it runs, it will end by setting itself up to run again after a second has passed.

In the second example, this doesn't happen. So the function only runs once.

Answer (score 1):

They're not functionally identical.

In the first (working) snippet, on call of `slideShow()` it does it's thing, then schedules another call 1 second later.

The second version *only* schedules a call of the anonymous function *once*. At no point is the function call scheduled again